# I got UHD Samsung SmartTV but the web apps seem to be only in Full-HD

Tags: tizen, samsung-smart-tv

It seems that the default resolution for apps is only 1920x1080 pixel.
I wasn't able to find more about changing the resoultion to 3840x2160, after all it is supposed to be a 4k SmartTV.

Modifiying http://tizen.org/feature/screen.size.normal.1080.1920 to http://tizen.org/feature/screen.size.normal.2160.3840 only scaled the application down, with the same crappy resolution.

http://developer.samsung.com/tv/develop/guides/fundamentals/application-resolution/